# Writing my own Monero miner

Tags: mining-pools, miners

So I was trying to make my own Monero miner and I found out that it uses the Cryptonight hash algorithm and I found documentation for it and I can implement it. But then how do I connect my miner to a pool, there doesn't seem to be any API on any of the Monero mining pool websites. Can someone explain how I can connect my miner to a pool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pool miners talk to pools using JSON over HTTP. This is a fairly simple protocol, which is different from the one used by Bitcoin miners, but similar.
I don't know of a documentation for it, but you can easily see what it's doing by looking at cpu-miner.c in Wolf's miner (copy found on github, not the original):

https://github.com/okae/cpu_miner_wolf/blob/master/cpu-miner.c

For the other side of the communication, you can look at the pool server:

https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool/blob/master/lib/pool.js

Comment: I'm a web developer and I have a good understanding with networking. But that file is over 2000 lines and it's in c , although I know c , it's not my thing I'm a node.js guy. So is there something other simpler?

Comment: Well, you can look at the server side. I'll add a link to my answer.